# App Script-MailApp- "service invoke too many times" error despite not invoking too many times!! Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good day Dear All,
I am running ONLY ONE  time based trigger from this google account and Once in a day. I want that to send around 60-80 emails per day. Right after sending only 15-22 emails, the app script shows error "Error: Service invoked too many times for one day: email."

I know that the daily quota for sending the email in 100. So, why does it count too many times! despite having 85 free emails!? here is my spreadsheet link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13M_Jn2ZU1lrzHWg0Y9CukVF-0OANT3CTWWPzn9Xqrr0/edit?usp=sharing

The tab name is "Email Sheet"

and the code is below

```
function sendEmailsDaily() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Email Sheet");
const sheetValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

for (let i = 1; i<sheetValues.length;i++) {
const row = sheetValues[i];
const senderName = "Tajdidul Islam";
const subject = row[1];
const cc = row[4];
const replyTo = 'tis@baumhueter.de';
const email = row[2];
const emailBody = row[3];
const sendEmailToCustomer = sendEmail(senderName,cc,subject,replyTo,email,emailBody);
sheet.getRange(i+1,6,1,1).setValue(sendEmailToCustomer);
}
}

function sendEmail(senderName, cc, subject, replyTo,email,emailBody) {
try{
  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,emailBody,{
    senderName: senderName,
    replyTo:replyTo,
    cc:cc
  })
const date = new Date();
return 'Email Sent-'+date;
}  
catch(error){
return 'Error: '+error.message;
}
}
```

Please be kind to help me!! :)

Comment: Try putting a delay in the loop.  They often measure things like by a rate rather than a total number

Comment: Email send quotas also count emails sent from the Gmail app and might be reduced for newly created accounts.

Comment: @Cooper thanks in million!!
I just allowed by formula only 10 mails per hour and triggered it hourly and its working perfectly!

Comment: @Rubén
Thanks for your kind reply. Actually, I found the quotas were not problem in this case but the rate. Because, for my older IDs, it was the same. Now its working. Thanks again for helping our!!